# How to calculate difference in DATE based on status of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset,

```
D_DATE       BIN Number   Disposition    Unit Assigned        
2018-01-04    10005      SWO Issued      PLUMBING DIVISION     
2016-06-23    10005      SWO Issued      SCAFFOLD UNIT         
2016-06-23    10005      SWO Rescinded   SCAFFOLD UNIT         
2018-01-17    10005      SWO Rescinded   PLUMBING DIVISION  
2019-01-04    10006      SWO Rescinded   BEST SQUAD 
2018-12-21    10006      SWO Issued      BEST SQUAD
```

I want to create a new field name "duration" which will capture the time difference between SWO issued and rescinded for each BIN number. Note that, each BIN number can show up multiple times based on Date and different Unit. So, each unit can issue SWO on the same BIN number.

I am trying to get a output like this which will calculate the date difference in days on the BIN number by Unit and based on SWO Issued and Rescinded.

Output:

```
    D_DATE       BIN Number   Disposition    Unit Assigned         Duration
    2018-01-04    10005      SWO Issued      PLUMBING DIVISION     13 Days
    2016-06-23    10005      SWO Issued      SCAFFOLD UNIT         0 days
    2016-06-23    10005      SWO Rescinded   SCAFFOLD UNIT         0 days
    2018-01-17    10005      SWO Rescinded   PLUMBING DIVISION     13 days
    2019-01-04    10006      SWO Rescinded   BEST SQUAD            14 days
    2018-12-21    10006      SWO Issued      BEST SQUAD            14 days
```

I used this but it groupby on Unit rather than giving me individual BIN Number by each unit and their dispositions status,

```
df2 = df2.groupby('BIN Number')['D_DATE'].agg(['max','min'])

df2["Duration"] = df2['max'].sub(df2['min']).dt.days
print(df2)
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: Can you post your data sample as text? so we can provide a solution? have a read of [mcve]

Comment: @Datanovice I edited the post. please take a look if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

you need to groupby and use `diff` to calculate the delta in time values,

you can then merge onto your original df.

```
m = df.groupby(['BIN Number','Disposition','Unit Assigned']).agg(date_min=('D_DATE','min'),
                                            date_max=('D_DATE','max')).groupby(level=[0,2])\
                                            .diff().reset_index().dropna().drop('Disposition',axis=1)

df2 = pd.merge(df,m,on=['BIN Number','Unit Assigned'],how='left')
```

---

```
print(df2)

      D_DATE  BIN Number    Disposition      Unit Assigned date_min date_max
0 2018-01-04       10005     SWO Issued  PLUMBING DIVISION  13 days  13 days
1 2016-06-23       10005     SWO Issued      SCAFFOLD UNIT   0 days   0 days
2 2016-06-23       10005  SWO Rescinded      SCAFFOLD UNIT   0 days   0 days
3 2018-01-17       10005  SWO Rescinded  PLUMBING DIVISION  13 days  13 days
4 2019-01-04       10006  SWO Rescinded         BEST SQUAD  14 days  14 days
5 2018-12-21       10006     SWO Issued         BEST SQUAD  14 days  14 days
```

Comment: giving me this error, TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'

Comment: the pandas version is  '0.24.2'

Comment: df2 = df.copy()
m = df2.groupby(['BIN Number','Disposition ','Unit Assigned']).agg(date_min=('D_DATE','min'),
                                            date_max=('D_DATE','max')).groupby(level=[0,2])\
                                            .diff().reset_index().dropna().drop('Disposition',axis=1)

data = pd.merge(df2,m,on=['BIN Number','Unit Assigned'],how='left')'

Comment: @TahsinAlam ah my fault, you need pandas 0.25 or higher, can you upgrade ?

Comment: I updated it and it works now. Thanks a bunch. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Sort them with `Disposition` and use shift() to extract the difference. It then extracts even-numbered lines and updates odd-numbered lines.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = '''
D_DATE "BIN Number" Disposition "Unit Assigned"
2018-01-04 10005 "SWO Issued" "PLUMBING DIVISION"
2016-06-23 10005 "SWO Issued" "SCAFFOLD UNIT"
2016-06-23 10005 "SWO Rescinded" "SCAFFOLD UNIT"
2018-01-17 10005 "SWO Rescinded" "PLUMBING DIVISION"
2019-01-04 10006 "SWO Rescinded" "BEST SQUAD"
2018-12-21 10006 "SWO Issued" "BEST SQUAD"
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=' ')
df['D_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['D_DATE'])
# upper code append

df.sort_values(['D_DATE', 'BIN Number', 'Disposition'], inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['Duration'] = df['D_DATE'] - df['D_DATE'].shift(1)
df['Duration'][::2] = df['Duration'][1::2]
df.sort_values('index', inplace=True)
df.set_index('index', drop=True)

        D_DATE  BIN Number  Disposition Unit Assigned   Duration
 index                  
0   2018-01-04  10005   SWO Issued      PLUMBING DIVISION   13 days
1   2016-06-23  10005   SWO Issued      SCAFFOLD UNIT       0 days
2   2016-06-23  10005   SWO Rescinded   SCAFFOLD UNIT       0 days
3   2018-01-17  10005   SWO Rescinded   PLUMBING DIVISION   13 days
4   2019-01-04  10006   SWO Rescinded   BEST SQUAD          14 days
5   2018-12-21  10006   SWO Issued      BEST SQUAD          14 days
```

Comment: Its giving me error on this line, df2['Duration'][::2] = df2['Duration'][1::2]                  ValueError: cannot set using a slice indexer with a different length than the value

Comment: I've modified all the code I actually tried. Check it out.

Comment: Its still giving me the same error on this line, df['Duration'][::2] = df['Duration'][1::2]

Comment: Is there an error in the code I provided? Or is it an error in your data? Also, the number of 'SWO Issued' and 'SWO Rescinded' must be the same.

Comment: It was an issue with my pandas version thats why it was not working. No error with your code. Thanks for helping.